# XPath to locate an <TD> tag with a specific text in OnClick

Tags: xpath

I have the following HTML:

```
<td onclick="fbm_bet('53987976','1','6','')" class="bfbhlt">
```

Is it possible to use Xpath to locate the  looking for the number 53987976. Something similar to:

//td[@contains="53987988"]

Many thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//td[contains(@onclick,'53987976')]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a million!